# Linux, C using cat with exec(3)

Tags: c, linux, exec, system-calls, cat

I'm doing this little program that reads users arguments upon calling the program.
Simple calls like ls, rm, and so on were easy to do, what I can't figure out how to do is this:

cat file1 >> file2
What I want to do is to add content of one file to the other, not replace the content.

So if I do something like:
./programName add file1 file2

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "add")==0){
                char *parmList[] ={ "cat", argv[2], ">>",  argv[3], NULL}; 
                execv("/bin/cat", parmList);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The return is the two file printed on the console and

> cat: >>: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way doing this without cat?
ps: It has to be with exec(3).

EDIT: For anyone interested, the replies helped me figure out a way to do it altough I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this.
What I did was to convert

> "cat", argv[2], ">>",  argv[3]

into one string and then use /bin/sh -c as suggested.

Here is the code

```
char parmList[180];
strcpy (parmList,"cat ");
strcat (parmList,argv[2]);
strcat (parmList," >> ");
strcat (parmList,argv[3]);
char *args[] = { "/bin/sh", "-c", parmList, NULL };
execve("/bin/sh", args, NULL);
```

Comment: I think `>>` could not be a parameter, it is interpreted by the shell which rederiects the output from the program to a file using a pipe.

Comment: If `exec*()` returns then it has failed, so it is quite strange to be returning success after it...

Comment: Oh, yes.. I've deleted already. After testing so many things some code is forgoten but since it had no impact I didn't bother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`>>` is a shell operator. You have not invoked a shell. You must do so if you want to use shell operators. Give `/bin/sh -c` a try.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I've tried diferent ways but no success.